# How to read website content in python

Tags: rss, html-parsing, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to write a program which reads articles (posts) of any website that could range from Blogspot or Wordpress blogs / any other website. As to write code which is compatible with almost all websites which might have been written in HTML5/XHTML etc.. I thought of using RSS/ Atom feeds as ground from extracting content.

However, as RSS/ Atom feeds usually might not contain entire articles of websites, I thought to gather all "posts" links from the feed using `feedparser` and then want to extract the article content from the respective URL.

I could get URL's of all articles in website (including summary. i.e., article content shown in feed) but I want to access the entire article data for which I have to use the respective URL.

I came across various libraries like `BeautifulSoup`, `lxml` etc.. (various HTML/XML Parsers) but I really don't know how to get the "exact" content of the article (I assume "exact" means the data with all hyperlinks, iframes, slides shows etc still exist; I don't want CSS part).

So, can anyone help me on it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want the HTML,images, and all files of the site or just want to grab parts of the HTML? Please be more specific.

Comment: @serk consider a blog post, I want the information exactly the way it was written. (save the CSS).

Comment: why not try `wget` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetching the HTML code of all linked pages is quite easy.

The hard part is to extract exactly the content you are looking for. If you simply need all code inside of the `<body>` tag, this shouldn't be a big problem either; extracting all text is equally simple. But if you want a more specific subset, you have more work to do.

I suggest that you download the requests and BeautifulSoup module (both avaible via `easy_install requests/bs4` or better `pip install requests/bs4`). The requests module makes fetching your page really easy.

The following example fetches a rss feed and returns three lists:

- `linksoups` is a list of the *BeautifulSoup* instances of each page linked from the feed
- `linktexts` is a list of the visible text of each page linked from the feed
- `linkimageurls` is a list of lists with the `src`-urls of all the images embedded in each page linked from the feed

  - e.g. `[['/pageone/img1.jpg', '/pageone/img2.png'], ['/pagetwo/img1.gif', 'logo.bmp']]`

```py
import requests, bs4

# request the content of the feed an create a BeautifulSoup object from its content
response = requests.get('http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot')
responsesoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

linksoups = []
linktexts = []
linkimageurls = []

# iterate over all <link>…</link> tags and fill three lists: one with the soups of the
# linked pages, one with all their visible text and one with the urls of all embedded
# images
for link in responsesoup.find_all('link'):
    url = link.text
    linkresponse = requests.get(url) # add support for relative urls with urlparse
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(linkresponse.text)
    linksoups.append(soup)

    linktexts.append(soup.find('body').text)
    # Append all text between tags inside of the body tag to the second list

    images = soup.find_all('img')
    imageurls = []
    # get the src attribute of each <img> tag and append it to imageurls
    for image in images:
        imageurls.append(image['src'])
    linkimageurls.append(imageurls)

# now somehow merge the retrieved information.
```

That might be a rough starting point for your project.

Comment: why you were using `requests`?

Comment: I just think it's a lot more convenient and practical than urllib, urllib2 or urllib3. You might want to have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). I assure you it's very nice and pythonic :) This could also be done with one oft the standard libraries; it's more like a personal preference.